# Extract item from list

Tags: r

I have generate the below list and I want to extract the cor value (the last value) only. Is there a way to do that? I tried using $estimate to do that, but to no avail. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
[[6]]

Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  cer[, x] and par[, y] 
t = 109.0053, df = 1898, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
0.9221188 0.9345283 
sample estimates:
cor 
0.9285826 #this value
```

output from str(list):

```
$ :List of 9
..$ statistic  : Named num 68.5
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
..$ parameter  : Named int 1898
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
..$ p.value    : num 0
..$ estimate   : Named num 0.844
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "cor"
..$ null.value : Named num 0
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "correlation"
..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
..$ method     : chr "Pearson's product-moment correlation"
..$ data.name  : chr "cer[, x] and par[, y]"
..$ conf.int   : atomic [1:2] 0.83 0.856
.. ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without the output from either `dput` or `str` on your list.

Comment: edited by adding str(list)

Comment: I already answer you in your previous post!

Answer (score 3):

> < mind.read >
>
> It appears that you gave a list containing the results of
>   `cor.test(..., method = 'pearson')`
>
> < \mind.read >

If this list is called `z`

then

```
 sapply(z, '[[', 'estimate')
```

will extract the `estimate` element from each element of `z`

It is useful to remember fortune(312)

```
fortune(312)

The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other
magic if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning
yourself into a toad.
   -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is
      stored in y via x$y rather than x[[y]])
      R-help (February 2012)
```